# Token will not refresh when using spotipy and Spotify Web API

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to use the code from the [Spotipy docs](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/) in order to see how Client Authorization Code Flow works. It worked at first but after a while I get this error: Couldn't refresh token. Response Status Code: 400 Reason: Bad Request. I haven't edited the code from the docs at all besides adding in the client credentials to the code. Thanks!
This is my code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

scope = "user-library-read"

client_id='xxxxxxx'

client_secret='xxxxxx'

redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5000/callback"
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope,client_id=client_id,client_secret=client_secret,redirect_uri=redirect_uri))

results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
for idx, item in enumerate(results['items']):

    track = item['track']

    print(idx, track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the access code.

You can do so following spotipy library here
https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/?highlight=refresh#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth.refresh_access_token

That's why you usually get 400 Reason: Bad Request | 403 Reason: Forbidden

Comment: I tried that but it didn't end up working. It does work for different scopes so I just changed the scope to "user-library-read,playlist-modify-public" and it fixed the problem.